# How to get the last row per metric BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Data:

```
+-------+------------+-----------------------+
| value |   metric   |  timestamp            |
+-------+------------+-----------------------+
| 30    | tempA      |  2019-01-12T01:00:00  |
| 28    | tempA      |  2019-02-12T02:00:00  |
| 25    | tempB      |  2019-03-12T03:00:00  |
| 60    | humidityA  |  2019-04-12T04:00:00  |
| 15    | tempC      |  2019-05-15T01:00:00  |
+-------+------------+-----------------------+
```

I want to get the last known value for certain temp metrics. I came up with:

```
SELECT
  metric,
  value,
  timestamp,
  seqnum
FROM (
  SELECT
    metric,
    value,
    timestamp,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY metric ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS seqnum
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE
    metric IN ('tempA', 'tempB') )
WHERE
  seqnum = 1
```

This partitions the whole table, which may take some time. Is there a more performant/efficient way to get the last row per metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array aggregation can be faster since it only needs to keep the top row in memory due to the LIMIT 1:

```sql
SELECT
  metric,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(value, timestamp)
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM
  `project.dataset.table`
WHERE
  metric IN ('tempA', 'tempB')
GROUP BY metric
```